# How to order string dates in C using values from a object of a structure

Tags: c, sorting

I´ve been doing a project in `C` about making a game calendar and saving it in a file so it can be read in the next execution. And right now i´m developing a function that should sort the games by date from the latest to the eldest.

Here is some code that i´ve already tried:

```
    void ordenarjogos(jogo games[JOG], int njog){
  int i,j;
  long int arr[5], t ;
  char str[20][20],troca[20];
  for(i = 0; i <= njog; i++)
    strcpy(str[i], games[i].data);
    for(i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
    {
      for (j = 0; j <= 3 - i; j++)
      {
        if ( arr[j] > arr[j + 1] )
        {
          t = arr[j] ;
          arr[j] = arr[j + 1] ;
          arr[j + 1] = t ;
          strcpy ( troca, str[j] ) ;
          strcpy ( str[j], str[j + 1]) ;
          strcpy ( str[j + 1], troca ) ;
        }
      }
    }
    for(i = 0; i < njog; i++)
      printf("%s\n",str[i]);
}
```

I'm not sure if this algorithm even works the way i want it to work but the fact is that it doesn't print what we want it to print.

Our inputs are theese: 10-10-2011; 10-10-2020; 10-10-2022.
[image: Our output was this:]

Comment: How about you convert to a type that is directly comparable. Date/time functions, or use ISO date format YYYY-MM-DD.

Comment: Is `njog` always less than 19?

Comment: Note: indexes in C go from `0..n-1` so `for(i = 0; i <= 3; i++)` should probably be `for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)`

Comment: Where does `arr` get its values? You use it uninitialized in `if (arr[j]..`

Comment: `qsort` is a library function that can sort your array: `qsort(games, njog, sizeof(*games), compare_games)`. You just need to define `int compare_games(const void *p0, const void *p1) { const jogo *g0 = p0; const jogo *g1 = p1; .. compare g0 and g1 by date, returning -1, 0 or 1; }`

Comment: Im going to try to convert to time